# How to authorize Angular5 app against SpringBoot backend using CAS

Tags: angular, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, cors

I've been recently coding a WebApp with the following components:

**Backend:** SpringBoot API with SpringSecurity that authorises against a 3rd party CAS server.

**Frontend:** Angular5 app which basically queries the API to get information.

**Problems:** I actually have two problems:

- How can I synchronize the CAS authentification between front and backend?
- How do I avoid CORS problems when backend redirects the frontend to the login page?

Currently if I try accessing a resource in the backend directly it redirects me to the CAS login page if I'm logged out and everything works fine. But if I access the resource from the Angular side I run into

> CAS login redirection runs into Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB)
>   blocked cross-origin response.

For the second problem I've tried everything I've found in the internet without much success. I've already added *@CrossOrigin* to my controller and I don't have CORS issues if I deactivate security but can't find how to avoid it when redirecting to the 3rd party login.

If more information is needed I'll be glad to provide it :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a consultant working with a major univesity where there are now seveal spring boot / Angular applications, and we have solved this problem by bundling the Angular app into the back-end application's static resources, so that the Angular app is served by the embedded web server.

In this way, the back-end's CAS filter protects access to the Angular app as well.

The only thing that we had to add to this was an Http interceptor in the Angular that catches the Http 401 error that can happen if the Angular app makes a service call after the CAS token has expired. The interceptor redirects to a route in the Spring Boot app that in turn redirects to the CAS server.

Comment: Yeah I read about SpringBoot serving the Angular index.html and this way everything gets protected by the backend but I was opting for that as a last resort option. But I'll totally do it that way and set it as answer if no better solution arises. Thanks! :)

Comment: I tried what you said and there's something I don't trully understand:

If I don't protect the Angular App with CAS, when it tries querying the backend it run into CORS when the backend tries redirecting to the login page.

If I protect the Angular App (basically by requiring "/*" to be authenticated in the SecurityCOnfig, then it properly redirects to the login without running into CORS.

And I'm really surprised about that since all the requests are coming now from the same server.

Comment: This solution also slows down development a lot since now, everytime a change happens I have to mvn clean install the whole thing and deploy to tomcat. Any suggestions on that side?

Comment: Not sure about why you are running into the other issues, but for UI development, I start up the spring boot app, log into the app (so that my browser has the CAS token), keep that browser tab open, and then run the Angular part again, with it's Dev server ("npm start" from the root of the Angular app), which makes the dev copy.of the app available on port 4200. This requires that you set up Angular's.proxy configuration to forward your service requests from port 4200 to whatever port Spring Boot is serving on. Then you can just modify the Angular app, and it will automatically reload.